# How to SELECT and sort it by parent-children in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id  parent_id   name    address     email   telephone
2   NULL        name    address     email   phone
3   NULL        name2   address2    email2  phone2
4   NULL        name3   address3    email3  phone3
5   NULL        name4   address4    email4  phone4
6   NULL        name6               email6  phone6 
7   5           name7               email7  phone7 
8   NULL        name8               email8  phone8
```

And I want to do a SELECT on it so I select all the rows, but if a row has a parent it will be displayed after the parent. So in this case the rows will look like this

```
id  parent_id   name    address     email   telephone
2   NULL        name    address     email   phone
3   NULL        name2   address2    email2  phone2
4   NULL        name3   address3    email3  phone3
5   NULL        name4   address4    email4  phone4
7   5           name7               email7  phone7 
6   NULL        name6               email6  phone6 
8   NULL        name8               email8  phone8
```

The row with id=7 goes before the one with id=6 because the parent_id of the one with id=7 is 5 so it is placed directly after that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a `case` statement in your `order by` clause:

```
select * 
from yourtable
order by case when parentid is null then id else parentid end, parentid
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87901c/2)

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking